# Java JPanel combobox that holds object types

Tags: java, swing, class, object, jpanel

So far from what I have seen combo boxes can only hold string and int types of values but this is what I am trying to achieve.

```
Class Node
{
  //code here
}

Node a = new Node();
Node b = new Node();

//I am wondering if I can somehow achieve something like
Node item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

So I want the combo box to hold items of type Node. The combo box will allow for a and b values but when selected they will register as Node objects. I am not sure that is even possible but just wondering. Thanks for input :)

Comment: What do you want to display to represent each node object?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html contains information about how to use custom objects inside a combobox

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JComboBox is able to contain any type of Object.
As of 1.7, you can also use the template definition to define the type contained.

Comment: Displayed value will use toString() from your object by default, unless you specify a ListCellRenderer.